# Trying to select named Excel 2007 Table in existing Workbook and insert row

Tags: c#, excel

I have an Excel template which I am opening, which has a pie chart bound to a table (ListObject), and I want to insert rows into the table. There are plenty of examples of how to ADD a table into a worksheet, but I can't find anywhere that lets me select the table.

I have tried:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Reflection;

oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Open(LastFile));
oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
Excel.ListObject ValList = oSheet.ListObjects("ValueData");
```

but that gives the compile error:

> Non-invocable member 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet.ListObjects' cannot be used like a method. (CS1955)

I have also tried doing it with a macro, then trying to convert the VB to C#, but still with no joy.

For information, I am relatively new to C# Excel automation, although I have done quite a lot in C# and have done Excel COM object work using other languages.

Comment: Change `("ValueData")` to `["ValueData"]`?

Comment: Also please do not use `ActiveSheet` Excel upon opening always displays the sheet which was visible last when you closed the file. And that sheet might not have the table. use something like this `oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.Worksheets.get_Item(1);` Replace `1` by the relevant sheet number.

Answer (score 0):

good morning,

mr.Reband is right, i think... maybee [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb907064%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is worth a look? as the error says, taken the MSDN link into account, i think, `oSheet.ListObjects` is a field or property, rather than a method. so, your invocation is not allowed. cheers!